# Automation error - serenity bdd - selenium - java - chrome - jenkins

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

Found this error

```
net.thucydides.core.webdriver.DriverConfigurationError: 
WebDriver was unable to create a new instance of type class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
WebDriver reported the following message: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

After try a lot of things like

- Install chromedriver and google-chrome
- Set credentials
- Change file path
- Change google chrome capabilities...

Adding this capability worked for me :)

"--crash-dumps-dir=/tmp"